# Is their any tool that can create Ruby on Rails migration script of existing Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I wanted to know if there is any tool that can be used to create SQL migration script of existing database in Ruby on Rails?

Also is there any visual tool that can be used to write Ruby on Rails migration script?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dump of the schema using rake, which will allow you to recreate your database .  There isn't, AFAIK a visual tool to create migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way making a migration when already have a working database is to create a new migration, then manually put the schema dumped from db server, and add another line to import existing data.

3rd Rail has a builtin tool when you create a new migration. It has lots of other "wizards" for doing common ruby script tasks. But I found the IDE it self too slow especially when working on a imported project.